# Perl subtract values from two 2D arrays

Tags: arrays, perl

I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(sum);

my @a1=([1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9]);

my @a2=([4,3],
        [2,1]);

my @subtracted;

for (my $i=0; $i<=$#a2; $i++){
    for (my $j=0; $j<=$#a2; $j++){
        my $subtraction=$a1[$i][$j] - $a2[$i][$j];
        print "$subtraction\n";
        my $abs=abs($subtraction);
        push(@subtracted, $abs);
    }
}
my $sum=sum(@subtracted);
my $average=$sum/@subtracted;
print "Average=$average\n";

exit;
```

This prints:

```
-3
-1
2
4
Average=2.5
```

This is subtracting the following referenced elements:

```
$a1[0][0] - $a2[0][0]
$a1[0][1] - $a2[0][1]
$a1[1][0] - $a2[1][0]
$a1[1][1] - $a2[1][1]
```

But now I need it to do:

```
$a1[1][1] - $a2[0][0]
$a1[1][2] - $a2[0][1]
$a1[2][1] - $a2[1][0]
$a1[2][2] - $a2[1][1]
```

and print:

```
1
3
6
8
Average=4.5
```

So that the elements of @a2 are fixed but the elements of @a1 are moved 1 line and 1 column (the number of compared elements is always limited by the number of elements in @a2). But now I am completely stuck and have no idea of how to do it. So, thank you in advance for your ideas.

Comment: `$a1[$i+1][$j+1]` ??

Comment: Thank you. That certainly works but I am trying to place everything in a single for loop. For the arrays could be much bigger.

Comment: To run matrix operations fast on large data sets, look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Data_Language

Answer (score 1):

```perl
my $sum = 0;
for my $i (0..$#a2) {
   for my $j (0..$#{ $a2[0] }) {
      my $diff = $a1[$i+1][$j+1] - $a2[$i][$j];
      $sum += $diff;
   }
}

my $avg = $sum / ( @a2 * @{ $a2[0] } );
say "avg: $avg";
```

In a comment, you talk about wanting a single loop. It's unclear what you meant  by that, but I think you meant that you want to loop for every possible offset.

```perl
my $n = @a2;
my $m = @{ $a2[0] };

for my $ofs (0..$#a1-$#a2) {
   my $sum = 0;
   for my $i (0..$n-1) {
      for my $j (0..$m-1) {
         my $diff = $a1[$i+$ofs][$j+$ofs] - $a2[$i][$j];
         $sum += $diff;
      }
   }

   my $avg = $sum / ( $n * $m );
   say "ofs: $ofs, avg: $avg";
}
```

Many of the terms from the sum of one offset are in common with the terms of the sum of the previous offset.

[image: Illustration of common terms]

As you can see, it involves fewer operations to calculate the delta of two subsequent sums than to calculate the sum from scratch. We can take advantage of that to optimize the solution for larger arrays.

```perl
my $n = @a2;
my $m = @{ $a2[0] };
my $nm = $n * $m;

my $sum = 0;
for my $i (0..$n-1) {
   for my $j (0..$m-1) {
      $sum -= $a2[$i][$j];
   }
}

for my $i (0..$n-2) {
   for my $j (0..$m-2) {
      $sum += $a1[$i][$j];
   }
}

for my $ofs (0..$#a1-$#a2) {
   $sum += $a1[ $_     + $ofs ][ ($m-1) + $ofs ] for 0..$n-2;
   $sum += $a1[ ($n-1) + $ofs ][ $_     + $ofs ] for 0..$m-2;
   $sum += $a1[ ($n-1) + $ofs ][ ($m-1) + $ofs ];

   my $avg = $sum / $nm;
   say "ofs: $ofs, avg: $avg";

   $sum -= $a1[ $_ + $ofs ][ 0  + $ofs ] for 1..$n-1;
   $sum -= $a1[ 0  + $ofs ][ $_ + $ofs ] for 1..$m-1;
   $sum -= $a1[ 0  + $ofs ][ 0  + $ofs ];
}
```

For mass number crunching, you might want to look at [PDL](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL).

Comment: Thanks. I see that could work. I have actually reached a similar solution. But I still have a problem. Everything is added to the same array and the average is estimated for (3+1+2+4+1+3+6+8)/8=3.5 and I need an average for the first four numbers (3+1+2+4)/4=2.5 and an average for the second set of four numbers (1+3+6+8)/8=4.5.

Comment: First of all, you don't need an array. You just need the sum and the number of things you've summed. And you already know the latter is `@a2 * @{ $a2[0] }`. You want a fresh array/sum for each offset, so you need to place the array/sum in the offset loop (or else you'd need to use an array of arrays/sums, one for each offset). Answer updated.